# Unable to install Nuget package in my Xamarin Cross Platform Application

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am developing a xamarin cross platform that is composed of following projects

1)Portable

2)IOS

3)Android

4)UWP

I am facing an issue while installing NuGet package for the xamarin portable project. Actually the NuGet that i am trying to install is targeted on .net Framework version 4.5.2. So we need the .net Version 4.5.2 or higher in our application in order to install this library. However when i try to change target framework version in my project properties to 4.6 then also i am facing  the compatibility error that given package is not compatible with .net 4.5.
So what is the correct way that to set the .Net framework version in the project  so that i can install it any project.
I have also referred to this doc by Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/net-standard#comparison-to-portable-class-libraries
that shows compatibility matrix.

Comment: Why not use .NET standard? What is the nuget lib that you are trying to install?

Comment: remove the packages. Update. Add them again

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to .net standard 2.0. use these links
https://xamarinhelp.com/upgrade-pcl-net-standard-class-library/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/